# Operations from atomic.h seem to be non-atomic

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

The following code produces random values for both n and v. It's not surprising that n is random without being properly protected. But it is supposed that v should finally be 0. Is there anything wrong in my code? Or could anyone explain this for me? Thanks.

I'm working on a 4-core server of x86 architecture. The uname is as follows.

Linux 2.6.9-22.ELsmp #1 SMP Mon Sep 19 18:00:54 EDT 2005 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <asm-x86_64/atomic.h>

int n = 0;
atomic_t v;
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

#define LOOP 10000

void* foo(void *p)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < LOOP; i++) {
//        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        ++n;
        --n;
        atomic_inc(&v);
        atomic_dec(&v);
//        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }

    return NULL;
}

#define COUNT 50

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    pthread_t pids[COUNT];
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    atomic_set(&v, 0);

    for(i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
        pthread_create(&pids[i], &attr, foo, NULL);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
        pthread_join(pids[i], NULL);
    }

    printf("%d\n", n);
    printf("%d\n", v);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I'd like to say: thanks for asking a clearly worded, unambiguous question with full working source code.  I wish everyone would do that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can we get a look at the assembler output of the code (gcc -E, I think). Even thought the uname indicates it's SMP-aware, that doesn't necessarily mean it was compiled with CONFIG_SMP.

Without that, the assembler code output does not have the `lock` prefix and you can find your cores interfering with one another.

But I would be using the pthread functions anyway since they're portable across more platforms.

Comment: Thanks. I found no lock prefix in gcc -E output. It will work simply adding #define CONFIG_SMP before including <atomic.h>. 

Acutally this piece of code is used for testing efficiency of different thread-safe increment approaches. It's not for production. :-)

Answer (score 6):

You should use gcc built-ins instead (see. [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html)) This works fine, and also works with icc.

```
int a; 
__sync_fetch_and_add(&a, 1); // atomic a++
```

Note that you should be aware of the cache consistency issues when you modify variables without locking.

Answer (score 4):

[This old post](http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0607.1/0952.html) implies that

- It's not obvious that you're supposed to include this kernel header in userspace programs
- It's been known to fail to provide atomicity for userspace programs.

So ... Perhaps that's the reason for the problems you're seeing?

Comment: Thanks for you information. I just wonder why linux kernel not exposing these useful primitives to userland programs. They are more lightweight and efficient than pthread_mutex approach.

Comment: @hank, well, the kernel actually does. Its glibc that makes it confusing.

Comment: @Hank: Well, because they don't work. Atomic operations require privileged operations on some platforms, which have to be done very differently from kernel and userland.

Comment: @TimPost: It only does the the point that the header is not guarded by `#ifdef __KERNEL__`. But they won't work on many platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Linux kernel `atomic.h` is not usable from userland and never was. On x86, some of it might work, because x86 is rather synchronization-friendly architecture, but on some platforms it relies heavily on being able to do privileged operations (older arm) or at least on being able to disable preemption (older arm and sparc at least), which is not the case in userland!